# How to build and deploy iOS application in a cloud?

Tags: macos, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have an iOS application, which I can build and deploy with my MacBook.

Now I would like to automate this for CI/CD.

Is it possible?

I found following ways:

MacOS under Oracle Virtual box on non Mac machine. Works but in gray legal zone.

AWS mac.metal instance. Too expensive, since they require to rent instance for at least 24 hours.

CircleCI. Problems with 2-factor authorization.

Is there any common, clean and accepted way to do this?

Comment: Use Azure Devops. I have been using it for years. It's free for the first 5 users and has a free mac build agent. We go straight from pull requests to app-store. No Mac needed.

Comment: Can they solve 2-factor authentication?

Answer (score 0):

[Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) ([documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions)) supports building on macOS.  That's probably going to be the easiest method for many people, because it's all built into Github, which is what almost everyone is using.

Comment: How do they solve 2-factor authorization?

Comment: @Dims You'll have to be more specific about what you mean by that. What two-factor authentication are you thinking about? Authenticating what and to whom? (Github can certainly do two-factor for log-in to Github, but I'm guessing maybe that isn't your question?)

Comment: Have you ever deployed iOS apps?

Comment: Yes. I don't see how that helps to work out what the two-factor authentication problem you have is, though. Are you talking about submitting to the App Store using an account with 2FA enabled? In which case you should generate an app password and use altool to upload.

Comment: Yes 2FA = two-factor authentication. Does Github can automate this thing with `altool` etc?

Comment: (I'm aware of what 2FA stands for, thank-you.) You can make it run what you like. You'll need to generate an app password to use altool, but it should work just fine.

Comment: Do you have any example workflow which is deploying `iOS` from `Github Actions`?